# React native "'AIRMapCoordinate.h' file not found" error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-maps

I stuck with a problem with Xcode. I upgraded one package for my react-native project (react-native-track-player@2.0.0-rc13) and after that when I tried to build the project, it does have problems with some headers in the "react-native-maps@0.26.1" package. It shows this error:

```
'AIRMapCoordinate.h' file not found
```

I realized that this error happening because Xcode can't find those headers and those headers are in this directory:
$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/ios/AirMaps

So I added this path to "Header search paths" but it still can't find those headers. I also delete pods and re-install them and cleaned the project build folder but I still have the same problem.
Do you have any ideas about what goes wrong here?

Comment: facing the same issue. Did you got it working?

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67945288/3437900